# Google_drive gem crashing on oAuth2 authentication

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, rubygems

On Google Drive gem I used to make the authentication using the config.json, like the [gem readme suggests](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby):

```
{
"client_id": "xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"client_secret": "xxxxxxxxx",
"scope": [
   "https://docs.google.com/feeds/",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
   "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
],
"refresh_token": "1/xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

But I'm getting an error on oAuth2 authentication:

> /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:2283:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate oauth2-1.1.0, because jwt-1.5.4 conflicts with jwt (< 1.5.2, ~> 1.0) (Gem::ConflictError)

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got past this, but I came across this question when having a similar issue.

I kept trying `gem list` to verify I had the proper versions of oauth2 and jwt, and I did.

The solution for me was that the script I was running was apparently access a different version of ruby through rvm, which had a different jwt gem version installed. 1.5.4

Once I did `rvm use ruby-2.3.0` which had jwt-1.5.4 I was able to do `gem uninstall jwt -v 1.5.4`. Then back to `rvm use ruby-2.1.5` which is my default and I was able to run everything with no problems.